# Dynamically change desktop background from bash script

Tags: gnome, desktop, wallpaper

Is it possible to change the GNOME desktop background during some period of time by just a random phrase from the list on black screen? Will is seriously load the CPU and consume battery life?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
ex_bg=$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri)
str=$(shuf -n1 list)
convert -background black -fill white -pointsize 72 label:"$str" /tmp/new_bg.jpg
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///tmp/new_bg.jpg"
sleep 20
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "$ex_bg"
```

It converts a random phrase from the file "list" to a jpeg and displays it for 20s, then set the old background.

For gnome 2, you have to use `gconftool-2` :

```
gconftool-2 -s --type string /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename "file"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also put videos and `xscreensaver`s on your background (also in `compiz`) with [`xwinwrap`](http://tech.shantanugoel.com/projects/linux/shantz-xwinwrap)